# Chargify Cancel Subscription: How to set cancellation message

Tags: chargify

[The doc](https://reference.chargify.com/v1/subscriptions/cancel-subscription) says that you can use the `cancellation_message` parameter/field when sending a request. I've tried both URL parameters and a field in JSON body, but none of these set the `cancellation_message` in the response to anything but `null`.

```
curl -H "authorization":"Basic somelongkeybase64=" -X DELETE https://myapp.chargify.com/subscriptions/17356012.json?cancellation_message=Application%20deleted

curl -H "authorization":"Basic somelongkeybase64=" -H Content-Type:application/json -d '{"cancellation_message":"Application deleted"}' -X DELETE https://myapp.chargify.com/subscriptions/17356169.json
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer from Chargify support team.
The `cancellation_message` should be wrapped into `subscription` in the request body:

```
{
  'subscription': {
    'cancellation_message': 'Canceling the subscription via the API'
   }
}
```

So the working `curl` request looks like the following:

```
curl -H "authorization":"Basic somelongkeybase64=" -H Content-Type:application/json -d '{"subscription":{"cancellation_message":"Application deleted"}}' -X DELETE https://myapp.chargify.com/subscriptions/17356169.json
```

Hope it can help someone, too.